# Can't migrate my database on RDS from laravel app

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-rds

initially I had a bunch of connection problems between my EC2 and RDS instances. I fixed all those with a few security rules.

now when running `php artisan migrate:fresh` I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3554 Access to system table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' is rejected. 
(Connection: mysql, SQL: drop table `columns_priv`,`component`,`db`,`default_roles`,`engine_cost`,`func`,`general_log`,`global_grants`,`gtid_executed`,`help_category`,`help_keyword`,`help_relation`,`help_topic`,`innodb_index_stats`,`innodb_table_stats`,`password_history`,`plugin`,`procs_priv`,`proxies_priv`,`rds_configuration`,`rds_global_status_history`,`rds_global_status_history_old`,`rds_heartbeat2`,`rds_history`,`rds_replication_status`,`rds_sysinfo`,`replication_asynchronous_connection_failover`,`replication_asynchronous_connection_failover_managed`,`replication_group_configuration_version`,`replication_group_member_actions`,`role_edges`,`server_cost`,`servers`,`slave_master_info`,`slave_relay_log_info`,`slave_worker_info`,`slow_log`,`tables_priv`,`time_zone`,`time_zone_leap_second`,`time_zone_name`,`time_zone_transition`,`time_zone_transition_type`,`user`)
```

it's clearly connected to the correct DB because it's trying to delete tables with the RDS prefix but it's failing, what should I do here?

**Update** I figured out that this is an probably an internal DB I accessed. the problem is I can't figure out which DB I should access now.

setting `DB_DATABASE` to `mysql` returns the error above.
setting it to `database-1` (my RDS instance ID) returns this error `Unknown database 'database-1'`

moreover, as you can see here, in my dashboard the DB name is empty, I couldn't find anywhere to change this option.

I am also on the free-tier for both RDS and EC2 if that matters
[image]

Comment: You seem to be pointing your migration to the mysql database within mysql that contains the system tables and views

Comment: @Shadow indeed. I updated my post with more info

Comment: You probably need to create a database within your instance

Comment: Please share more details about the migration you try to run. Also, are you sure this is a problem directly related to AWS or EC2?

Comment: `DB name` being empty just indicates that you did not specify a database name to be created, when you created the instance. Just connect to your instance and `CREATE DATABASE my_db_name;` and then specify `my_db_name` in your application's config.